# When setting Storyboard.TargetName on custom control in trigger, throws exception

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I have custom button control FancyButton (created for reuse obviously) like this below and some code behind (mainly dependency properties):

```
<Button x:Class="Views.Controls.FancyButton"
         ...... >

    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ....
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

Below, a usage of this control, trigger should start to switch popup property on mouse up but instead of it I'm facing exception that says

> 'Popup' name cannot be found in the name scope of
>   'Views.Controls.FancyButton'.

```
<controls:FancyButton x:Name="ChooseButton" ServerConnection="{Binding CurrentServer}">
<Button.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger SourceName="ChooseButton" RoutedEvent="UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Popup" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(IsOpen)">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="True"/>
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Button.Triggers>
</controls:FancyButton >
<Popup Placement="Bottom" Name="Popup">
    ..........
</Popup>
```

Previous solution - when used Button control directly - was working as expected but I had a XAML duplication.

What does it change and how to make it work?

Comment: It is because of naming convention , Please try after setting Popup name to something else e.g.Popup1.

Comment: Thanks for hint @AshokRathod but it didn't help, still the same issue, following you I changed also Popup Name= to Popup x:Name, result the same.

Comment: please change control name to popup1 as  its conflicting with system reserved words.

Comment: Yep, I just did it after you first answer, the same exception is thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Instead of using Storyboard.TargetName attached property I used Storyboard.Target and proper binding as below:

```
<Button.Triggers>
<EventTrigger SourceName="ChooseButton" RoutedEvent="UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=popup1}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(IsOpen)">
                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="True"/>
            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Cheers